# Conditional merge / get duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas

my initial data looks like

```
>>> left
        id      a
0  3397088   1968
1  3420060   1969
2  3420089   1969

>>> right
       lid   foo  amin  amax
0  3397088     1  1968   2000
1  3420060     2  1969   2000
2  3420089     1  1969   2000
```

What I want to do is a merge of the sort

```
result = pd.merge(left, right, how=inner, left_index="id", right_index="lid")
```

However, there is sometimes more than one right row for a left row. However, there is always only one that also satisfies `(right.amin <= left.a) & (right.amax >= left.a)`. So, the nicest thing would be to somehow put this into the merge. I did not manage to, so my second approach will be to first to a `how=right` merge, grab all the rows and then go group-wise:

As it seems to be less performant, I prefer to find the duplicates using `result.set_index('id').index.get_duplicates()` rather then `result.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)`. However, this leaves me with a list of duplicate (and float) indices:

```
Out[48]: 
[3419915.0,
 3419947.0,
(...)
 6009542.0]
```

So then, in order to get the duplicate rows, I thought of doing

```
duplicates = pd.DataFrame(right.set_index(['lid']).index.get_duplicates(), columns={'id'})
right.set_index(['PATENT'], inplace=True)
rows = right.ix[duplicates['id']]
```

But now I am stuck: What is the smart way of doing next? - or is there a neater approach at all?

Comment: Are you sure that `result = pd.merge(left, right, left_on="id", right_on="lid", how='left')` do what you want?

Comment: I am doing `how='right'` - this will give me all the left rows (yes, given the database, no left row will drop in the process), but in addition, all the right rows that match (whenever there is more than one per left row, all of them). Did this answer your question?